# Matching two dataframes based on a common ID and the closest timestamp (less than 5 min) in R

Tags: r, dataframe, join, dplyr, merge

I have two datasets which I wish to merge, the first one looks like
dat1=

| ID | timestamp |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-10-26 06:37:23 |
| 2 | 2020-10-26 07:43:16 |
| 3 | 2020-10-26 09:36:52 |

Meanwhile, the second dataset looks like
dat2=

| ID | timestamp | x1 | x2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-10-26 07:55:23 | a | c |
| 1 | 2020-10-26 06:39:23 | b | b |
| 1 | 2020-10-26 08:28:39 | c | e |
| 2 | 2020-10-26 10:56:12 | d | a |
| 2 | 2020-10-26 18:39:52 | e | e |
| 3 | 2020-10-26 09:37:52 | a | a |
| 3 | 2020-10-26 10:16:17 | b | f |
| 3 | 2020-10-27 07:54:45 | c | d |
| 3 | 2020-10-27 08:25:44 | d | a |

The final output should match based on common ID and the closest timestamp but the time difference should be less than 5 min.

I referred some similar answers prescribing the data.table package and one even with the base package using apply functions. However, the matches are quite weird with the actual difference between the timestamps being too high.

The final output would look something like this

| ID | timestamp | timestamp.y | x1 | x2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-10-26 06:37:23 | 2020-10-26 06:39:23 | b | b |
| 2 | 2020-10-26 07:43:16 | NA | NA | NA |
| 3 | 2020-10-26 09:36:52 | 2020-10-26 09:37:52 | a | a |

Can someone please help me with this. The actual datasets are quite large.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the dfata frames shown reproducibly in the Note at the end, perform a left join using the indicated condition grouping by dat1 rows and taking the minimum seconds difference over the matched rows.  Remove the seconds difference column (4) at the end.  Note that there are 60 * 5 seconds in 5 minutes.

```
library(sqldf)

out <- sqldf("select a.ID, 
              a.timestamp, 
              b.timestamp [timestamp.y], 
              min(abs(a.timestamp - b.timestamp)) seconds, 
              b.x1, 
              b.x2
  from dat1 a
  left join dat2 b on a.ID = b.ID and
                      abs(a.timestamp - b.timestamp) < 60 * 5
  group by a.rowid")[-4]
out$timestamp.y <- as.POSIXct(out$timestamp.y, origin = "1970-01-01")

# check
all.equal(out, target)
## [1] TRUE
```

### Note

Assume the inputs and target below shown reproducibly.  Note that the timestamp columns have POSIXct class.

```
dat1 <-
structure(list(ID = 1:3, timestamp = structure(c(1603708643, 
1603712596, 1603719412), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "")), 
row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")

dat2 <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), 
timestamp = structure(c(1603713323, 1603708763, 1603715319, 
1603724172, 1603751992, 1603719472, 1603721777, 
1603799685, 1603801544), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), 
    x1 = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "a", "b", "c", "d"), x2 = c("c", 
    "b", "e", "a", "e", "a", "f", "d", "a")), row.names = c(NA, 
-9L), class = "data.frame")

target <-
structure(list(ID = 1:3, timestamp = structure(c(1603708643, 
1603712596, 1603719412), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), 
timestamp.y = structure(c(1603708763, 
NA, 1603719472), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), 
    x1 = c("b", NA, "a"), x2 = c("b", NA, "a")), row.names = c(NA, 
-3L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Thank you very much. After some initial hiccups with the installation of the sqldf package, it worked like a charm.